# How to launch jenkins jobs after Post deployment in TFS

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, tfs

I have automated build and deploy process in TFS by referring to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/790206/Deploying-Web-Applications-using-Team-Foundation.

After deployment I am validating deployed application by running selenium scripts via batch file by mentioning the path in **"post-test script path"**. Its executes the batch file and runs automated tests.

Now, I wanted publish these selenium results. So I have created jenkins jobs with email configured. So how to execute this job post deployment. I have tried by providing jenkins job trigger email in **"post-test script path"**, but it actually looking the path and throughs an error. So how to execute jenkins jobs post deployment.

Also, I am trying complete automation process, where it automatically build, deploy and run some selenium tests using TFS. If any body has better process please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Update: I have created batch file containing build url of jenkins and executed with "Post-test Script path". Also I have passed current TFS build number as an argument, which will used in subject of jenkins  results email to know for which build number results belongs to...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Command Line task in the new TFS 2015/VSTS build system to easily execute selenium tests.

[image: command like build task in tfs]

You can then easily configure and pass variables.

[image: build task order in tfs]

I would also recommend that you move to using release management tools for deployment. While a CD makes sense for development it is often not viable for a release pipeline and you need more meta data and approvals.

You can do this with the release management tools that come with TFS 2013+.